# Google Data Studio, Max Data limit?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, looker-studio

I'm creating charts with different google Cloud path (different Data Source) on a same report. What will be the maximum limit on data (cache) for each chart and cumulative total for the report ?

for example, I'm applying filter for date, as 5 years for a chart, may be about say 150 MB, will it able to show/load ? Similarly for each chart of the report, I apply same date filter for 5 yrs, and every chart have different Data Source. So, for one report, what will be Data Studio maximum data limit ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for Google Data Studio, there is no mention of a cache size limit. There is only a mention that you can use the cache to manage ["Data Freshness"](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039?ref_topic=6309857).

Additionally, judging by the comments on this document, each data source has it's own cache as you can configure when you wish to refresh said information based on the connector you are using.

Hope you find this useful!